# Loop Unfolding and Named Significant Bits

Tags: optimization, parsing, compiler, loops

I've been writing a Parser Compiler for the last seven or so years, and I recently got to the point (yet again, never satisfied) of structuring the portion dealing with the portions of the language that are valid at any given point.

In other parser compilers, I've seen them using cryptic `byte`/`int` arrays that refer to state transitions or what's valid in a follow context, or what have you.  I'm not terribly keen on 'magic numbers' that make sense to a state machine because I'm of the mind that they (the byte arrays) don't really help during debugging (at least not for me.)

To fix this issue, I plan on having a given language use a custom rolled `struct` which contains subsets to multiple enums.  Since the parser I'm writing aims to use path prediction rules are also present within this predictive set (not relevant to this discussion.)

I decided to make this structure emit a proper 'ToString' method that would explicitly outline what is valid, using the terms from the original language, if '=>' is valid, it'll show '=>'.

**Question Starts Here:**

This leads me to the problem: in a language with 575 different symbols (rule/token) this yields 18 32-bit values, or `2 ^ 575` different variations.  The single `ToString` method that results is over 7000 lines long.  It's effectively an unfolded loop over the set of elements that are possible.  I've added in logic to avoid stepping over areas that it can verify zero options are present.

**Is there a better way to do this?**  I could just check the values of the 'valid' enums and concatenate those, but it loses the important context and often creates longer strings because `OperatorOrPunctuator_LeftShiftAssign | OperatorOrPunctuator_RightShiftAssign | OperatorOrPunctuator_SemiColon` is longer than `OperatorOrPunctuator ['<<=', '>>=', ';']`.

I've included a link to the [file in question](http://www.abstraction-project.com/text/ToySharp/ToyReaderValidSymbols-1.html), there's also a [singleton set](http://www.abstraction-project.com/text/ToySharp/ToyReaderSymbolStore-Singletons.html) (most symbol references in linked files are links to reference) that would be used for experimenting.  On top of the Singletons I will (not done yet) also include an entry for every state within every production and prediction of the language.  This might seem like a lot, but in calculating the predictions for the language, there are currently 5,233,421 set comparisons made (union, symmetric difference, intersections, et cetera), but only 24,030 distinct sets.  If you do the math, that would yield `24,030 * 4 * 18` bytes of data (1,730,160.)

The goal of these is to provide decent context when a syntax error occurs, I think it might also be possible to generate fake error recovery tokens  if the full ahead set is available.  Though I wonder if a shortest path algorithm will need written to determine which 'guess' to use at a given state.

Comment: Are you familiar with Continuation-Passing Style?

Comment: Since I don't know what you mean, I'll go with... no?

Comment: You should look it up; I have a sense that might help you here.  Also, there might be five million possible permutations possible with your language syntax, but that does not mean that you have to account for every single one of them.  There might only be a few dozen *major* productions.  Check your [Formal Grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar); I think you'll find that you don't need 5 million definitions to represent your language.

Comment: Please re-read the statement.  I noted that there were 5 million **computations** on those sets.  There are only 24,030 different unique combinations that are utilized within the language.

Comment: Why is that important?

Comment: Anyway, the byte/int array is just an implementation detail; I suspect that you're describing either a *state engine,* or *continuation-passing style.*  Linq, for example, does not use byte arrays to keep track of itself.  Rather, it chains operators together in continuation-passing style to create a state-engine, and it's a lazily executed one at that (cf. `yield` `return` in C#).

Comment: Robert, fast reply for the win.  It was an aside in the off chance someone asked a question relative to the storage/computational requirements.  While not directly the focus, it might have been asked.  Would you be kind enough to provide a relevant link to the 'Continuation-Passing' style relative to this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style, although there are probably better (read: easier to digest) references than this. Try a Google Search for "Compiler continuation-passing style".  CPS is an artifact of Functional Programming; FP is uniquely suited to compiler development.

Comment: Surely you don't have 575 different token types... Why is a simple `Symbol("=>")` (or pass in an enum, which gets looked up by a Dictionary/HashTable) insufficient?

Comment: In a prediction, there might be a fairly large list of what's valid next due to potentially a few hundred parse paths being active at any one point.  Encoding this information within a condensed form that, has a string-form available for debugging, will help someone trying to figure out what's going awry in their debugger.  I could just encode all 24k relevant string variations into a switch but I feel it's nicer to have something you can play with.  There aren't 575 tokens, but the predictive algorithms allow rules to be present due to reductions during prediction.

Comment: The enum with a hash/dictionary lookup I don't think will work because each enum represents a set of multiple possible symbols, so I'd have to have 2 ^ 575 entries in that dictionary for the lookup to work.

Comment: @RobertHarvey is your solution for the issue of creating the results of this ToString method or a parsing mechanism?

Comment: @Alex I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do and why it has to be so complicated, but I'm a fan of the [Marpa parser generator](http://savage.net.au/Marpa.html), which uses a modified Earley algorithm. The core of the Earley algorithm is that we maintain a set of currently active productions, and the current position of each production. This can be used to predict which rules or tokens may occur at any given position, which enables really great error messages. You could maybe ask Marpa's author Jeffrey Kegler (via IRC or the Google Groups mailing list) how he implemented these sets.

Comment: @AlexanderMorou: My suggestion is a response to your second paragraph.  In Functional Programming, you don't have these kinds of byte arrays at all; rather, the "state" is held in the method calls (i.e. continuations).  That's the reason I didn't post it as an answer; it's probably a radically different approach than the one you're using, but you did say you didn't like the byte array approach.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Gotcha, how does this handle backtracking, ambiguities, and which rules would take precedence?

Comment: @amon the focus of the project is a deterministic system.If I recall correctly aren't Early parsers non-deterministic and work through evaluating all paths simultaneously? The goal here is if two parse paths yield the exact same result it's a irreducible error, so I don't allow for ambiguities of that nature. However, for the most part, I haven't had any issues with the mechanism I'm using to predict all paths up to now. The question is focused on whether there's a more streamlined means to handle named significant bits in large bit-arrays. I'm guessing by the lack of focus on it, there is not